# How to sort items in a dropdown list ignoring accents using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to sort my dropdown list by a crescent order.

The following code (see snippet below) does what I want. However, it doesn't ignore the accents, and this is what I aim.

Could someone help me with that?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    $("#MyID").html($("#MyID option").sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
 }))
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="MyID">
          <option> Papél </option>
          <option> Árvore </option>
          <option> Carne </option>
          <option> Banana </option>
          <option> Água</option>
          <option> Macaco</option>
          <option> Maçã</option>
     </select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **`localeCompare()`** for this purpose.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    $("#MyID").html($("#MyID option").sort(function (a, b) {
      return (a.text).localeCompare(b.text);
  //return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
 }));
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="MyID">
          <option> Papél </option>
          <option> Árvore </option>
          <option> Carne </option>
          <option> Banana </option>
          <option> Água</option>
          <option> Macaco</option>
          <option> Maçã</option>
     </select>
```

Refer this link for other methods:
http://www.jstips.co/en/sorting-strings-with-accented-characters/

Answer (score 1):

use [**localCompare**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_non-ASCII_characters)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    $("#MyID").html($("#MyID option").sort(function (a, b) {
 return a.text.localeCompare(b.text)
    }))
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="MyID">
          <option> Papél </option>
          <option> Árvore </option>
          <option> Carne </option>
          <option> Banana </option>
          <option> Água</option>
          <option> Macaco</option>
          <option> Maçã</option>
     </select>
```